# How to save bmp as pdf?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm saving a image but I need convert this image to pdf and save It. How can I do this?

Here is the code which I have used:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "image.bmp";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
            this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.ClientRectangle);
            using (var Stream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
            {
                bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: You can use iTextSharp. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115242/insert-an-image-in-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: You need to use a specific library for that ! see PDFSharp and many others !

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642280/jpg-to-pdf-convertor-in-c-sharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775048/save-pdf-to-jpeg-using-c-sharp and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a PDF library, such as [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/).

Here's some [sample code](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_an_image_in_original_size_20) to add an image to a PDF:

```
void DrawImage(XGraphics gfx, int number)
{
  BeginBox(gfx, number, "DrawImage (original)");

  XImage image = XImage.FromFile(jpegSamplePath);

  // Left position in point
  double x = (250 - image.PixelWidth * 72 / image.HorizontalResolution) / 2;
  gfx.DrawImage(image, x, 0);

  EndBox(gfx);
}
```

Comment: well, event here "Don't repeat your self principle" should normally work. We need to re-factor questions and answers not duplicating them !

Comment: Agreed. After posting this answer I saw the comment about dupes and voted to close :)

Comment: `PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
            XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
            XImage img = XImage.FromFile(source);

            xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
            doc.Save(destinaton);
            doc.Close();` How do I to generate a XImage from `Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);` for example..?

Comment: Well, you could either draw to the PDF directly, or you could save your Bitmap to a file and use the path when calling `XImage.FromFile(source)`.

Answer (score 0):

I use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to convert to PDF

Answer (score 0):

Pdf is a container format. So can't save a bitmap **as** a pdf, instead you have embed the bitmap **in** the pdf

iTextSharp is an perfect fit for this
See [Insert an Image in PDF using ITextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115242/insert-an-image-in-pdf-using-itextsharp)