# Extracting lines and other shapes using iTextsharp

Tags: itext

I want to extract the lines and other shapes in a PDF file and also need to get the position of lines and other shapes using itextsharp. So can anyone help for this??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That's not supported yet, so you'll have to write your own "GraphicsRenderInfo" class. Use "TextRenderInfo" and "ImageRenderInfo" for inspiration.

Comment: Then is there any way to extract the tables from the PDF file?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a table" in PDF, unless your PDF is Tagged. Is your PDF tagged?

Comment: My problem is there is a table in document and i export it to PDF. Now i want extract it back. How can i do this using iTextsharp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using LocationTextExtractionStrategy in itextSharp for text coordinate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513209/using-locationtextextractionstrategy-in-itextsharp-for-text-coordinate)

Comment: We have a communication problem, @Samo. You say that there is a table in your document. I say there isn't. I'm the PDF expert, so... maybe I'm right. When you say there's a table in your document, you say so because you see that table with your eyes. When I say there is no table in your document, I am right because a machine can *render* a table, but it doesn't know that the table is actually a table (unless the PDF is tagged). All it sees are glyphs and lines added at absolute positions. I'll also vote to close the question as it's indeed a duplicate of the question already answered by Chris.

Comment: Hi Bruno Lowagie, You said that, All it sees are glyphs and lines added at absolute positions.. So my question is How can i extract that lines or else at least i need to get start and end coordinate points of those lines.. Please let me know is it possible using iTextsharp or is it possible using any other library??