# Convert PDF to DOCX with Word interop

Tags: pdf, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, office-automation

Is this possible to convert PDF file into DOCX with MS Word Interop library?
I see that that was possible via the UI - I was wondering if it could be done programmatically as well

Comment: Can you add a link to what's possible with MS Word Interop library UI? I cannot find any solid info on being able to go PDF → Word.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the [Documents.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open) method for opening PDF and then saving it using the docx format. Other than that the Word object model doesn't provide anything for that.

Consider using any third-party components designed for such conversions
as Aspose.

Comment: I don't see anything specific about Word DOCX files in that XFinium link, or anywhere on the XFinium site... can you clarify/specify?

Comment: You may also take a look at Aspose.

Comment: See [C# Converting PDF file to Word doc and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024387/c-sharp-converting-pdf-file-to-word-doc-and-vice-versa)