# How to change colors of an existing PDF document using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am a total noob to working with PDF documents in C#. Can someone please give me an example of how can I change the background and text colors of an existing document using C#(I tried it via iTextSharp but failed to understand how it can change the color properties of a document).

Will really appreciate the help guys. Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Setting the background color is feasible: you search the text using the parser package classes, there-in extract the position, and either draw a colored rectangle at that very position in the UnderContent or use a highlighting annotation. Changing the color of the letters themselves can prove more difficult, though, especially as long as you want to do it cleanly; this requires you to do some iText low-level magic. Or (a less clean approach) you merely find the position of the letters in question and in the OverContent write them again at the same position in the new color.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight the text refer:

[Highlighting text ( colors ) of existing PDF using iTextsharp using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582706/highlighting-text-colors-of-existing-pdf-using-itextsharp-using-c-sharp)

And text color and fonts refer this:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/81/iTextSharp-Working-with-Fonts