# Highlight Some Part of PDF

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, pdf

This is strange but my client's requirement. He wanted to `highlight some part of PDF`. His PDF contains `only image`, so he want to highlight selected area of that image inside `PDF`. I know only about highlighting text. But I don't know about highlighting some part of PDF. Please help. I don't know how to do this.

I am doing project in `ASP.NET MVC 5(C#)`.

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you are handling the request to get the PDF file. A JavaScript/jQuery solution may not work since it runs on HTML pages and manipulates the DOM.. and PDF are transferred as binaries.. Maybe there is a Highlight Viewer plugin out there somewhere, for your client, behind all the relevant search parameters you can make on [Google](http://www.google.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iTextSharp. There is no direct method to highlight the image, instead you can do this by specifying the co-ordinates which you want to highlight.

Please take a look at the following link,  [Highlighting text ( colors ) of existing PDF using iTextsharp using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582706/highlighting-text-colors-of-existing-pdf-using-itextsharp-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I tried but issue I am facing is when I take coordinates on mousedown and mouseup event, that coordinates start from top left corner while pdf coordinates start from bottom left corner. so i dnt get exact result.

Comment: How are you displaying the pdf file? i mean using which tool are you displaying?